# How to Babelify (with React), Browserify, Uglify, and Watchify in one line

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs, uglifyjs, watchify

I want to avoid using Gulp or Grunt (anyone else tired of those?) and turn

```
/src
    /component
        index.jsx
    index.jsx
```

into

```
/dist
    bundle.min.js
```

using a one-line command that I can put in my `package.json` file:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "..."
...
```

I have been trying with variations of the `babel`, `babelify`, `browserify`, and `watchify` command lines to no avail. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
watchify src/index.jsx -t [babelify [--presets es2015,react]] -v -o bundle.js
```

...and there are many other variations I've tried.

**Update 1**:

I'm close.

```
watchify -v --extension=.jsx -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]\
         -g uglifyify src/index.jsx -o bundle.js
```

This works, but it doesn't detect changes to `src/components/index.jsx`.

**Update 2**:

If I exclude the (large) React library from the bundle, then everything works:

```
watchify -v --extension=.jsx -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]\
         -g uglifyify --no-bundle-external src/index.jsx -o bundle.js
```

...which makes me wonder if something is quietly going wrong and watchify is breaking [as described in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/64).

Comment: why not use webpack? there are a lot of tutorials and boilerplates using react with webpack, and without gulp, just use google with "react webpack boilerplate" or something like that.

Comment: Honestly I don't care what I use, as long as it fits on one line, and I don't have to jack with gulp files, grunt files, or config files.

Comment: Could it be better to split this into more npm script commands?

Comment: I was never able to get this work. I switched to webpack and, although I still can't do things in one line, the configuration was a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the option parameters. It worked for me then.

```js
watchify src/index.jsx -v -o bundle.js  -t [babelify [--presets es2015,react]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. It errors out on the JSX file.

Comment: Hm ok. I created the project like you described. In my index.jsx I wrote an empty function x(){}. And it was correctly bundled. I will put some real React code

Comment: Can i do this using gulp?